# How to run "sudo ipython notebook" in browser without using Anaconda "ipython notebook"?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-15.10

I have two pythons installed on my ubuntu

1. `sudo which python`
2. `which python`*(anaconda)*.

And both pythons have ipython installed in it. When I run `ipython notebook` *(anaconda)* it simply takes me to the browser and works perfectly. But, when I run it like  `sudo ipython notebook` *(calling from systems python)* it gives me an error. I want run ipython in browser in both cases.

What I do:

[image: Snapshot what I did!]

Comment: What use case do you have that requires `ipython notebook` to have sudo privileges ?

Comment: hey i resolved it using this command "sudo apt-get install ipython-notebook". Actually sudo pip doesn't work i think. Therefore i tried that and installed ipython-notebook and then i tried "sudo ipyton notebook" and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Iresolved it using this command `sudo apt-get install ipython-notebook`. Actually sudo pip doesn't work i think. Therefore i tried that and installed ipython-notebook and then i tried "sudo ipyton notebook" and it worked! :

Comment: So you just did not have notebook installed. There is nothing wrong with running it, under sudo. :)